# shell script taking last empty line of a file also

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a script:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

TODAY=$(date +%Y%m%d)
list=$1
FILE_NAME="IMEI.txt"
OUTFILE="${list}_list.out"

##########################################
if [ -z ${list} ]
then
    echo "Use the syntax ./add_imei.sh <list number>"
    exit 0
fi

while read LINE
do
    IMEI=`echo $LINE | 
        sed 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g'`
    END_SERIAL=`echo $IMEI |
        cut -c9- | sed 's/ //g' | 
                sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g'`
    echo \
        "CRE:EQU,${IMEI}0,${END_SERIAL},${list},,${TODAY};" \
            >> ${OUTFILE}i
done < "${FILE_NAME}"
```

The script will take 14 digit number from every line of the file `IMEI.txt`, build a command like:

```
CRE:EQU,777777777777770,777777,0,,20130611;
```

and save it in a seperate output file. Pretty simple job. Everything is working fine, but when I look into the output file I see this:

```
CRE:EQU,444444444444440,444444,0,,20130611;
CRE:EQU,555555555555550,555555,0,,20130611;
CRE:EQU,666666666666660,666666,0,,20130611;
CRE:EQU,777777777777770,777777,0,,20130611;
CRE:EQU,0,,0,,20130611; <-- *)
```

*) for the last empty line of the input line also (as i hit a last enter while saving the input file) it's building a command in output file which I don't want. Any quick, short and smart way to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while read LINE
do
    [ -z "$LINE" ] && continue
    IMEI=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g')
    END_SERIAL=$(echo $IMEI | cut -c9- | sed 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g')
    echo "CRE:EQU,${IMEI}0,${END_SERIAL},${list},,${TODAY};" >> ${OUTFILE}i
done < "${FILE_NAME}"
```

If the line is empty, continue with the next iteration of the loop.

Or have `sed` delete blank lines (containing blanks and tabs only) before feeding the file to the loop:

```
sed '/^[     ]*$/d' "$FILE_NAME" |
while read LINE
do
    IMEI=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g')
    END_SERIAL=$(echo $IMEI | cut -c9- | sed 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/[^ -~]//g')
    echo "CRE:EQU,${IMEI}0,${END_SERIAL},${list},,${TODAY};" >> ${OUTFILE}i
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first way worked fine for me. Somehow the second way is not working for me.

Comment: Oh bother - I had left the `< "$FILE_NAME"` after the loop, which overrode the input from the `sed` command.  I've removed that; the command should then work.

Comment: Thanks for trying @HankLangeveld, but the revised code was unreadable to me.  What size screen are you using that you get horizontal scrollbars on the code shown?  It has no scroll bars on my screen (1920x1400 or thereabouts).

Comment: Applying both the ways, i can see its not bulding a command for the last line, i.e its skipping the last line now:

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My screen size is irrelevant, as the browser shows plenty of room on the left and right.  Which browser do you use?  I'm always looking for the compromise; I don't want to change the actual working of the code and keep it all inside the text frame.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld: I use either Firefox or Chrome on Mac OS X or Linux, and on both of those, the code in my answer is not subject to the horizontal scroll-bar.  I'm puzzled to account for why you would not see the same as me — I have hi-res devices, so I wondered if that was somehow a factor.  But I'm seeing a good 8 characters of space after the longest lines in my answer. I wonder if it is a font issue instead of resolution? Having said that, I just used 'command +' 5 times to increase the font size, and while the material is very large, there is still no horizontal scroll-bar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the font could actually make a difference.  I work with a low res screen at home, and prefer larger, smoother fonts.  I can run some tests.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, First test: Internet Explorer shows the entire width of your code, and only shows a couple of millimetres of white in the left margin.  I think this conversation belongs in meta now.